# Move Image on window WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Here is my code :

```
                    <Image x:Name="Layer_22_copy" Height="542" Canvas.Left="16" Opacity="0.522" Source="gammon2_Images\Layer 22 copy.png" Canvas.Top="13" Width="315"/>
```

how can i change position of this image on Code Behind?
i am new in WPF.
thank you.

Comment: i want of move it on board (its backgammon game)
i converted psd style to XAML.

Comment: Check <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls">here</a> to see if this will help.  It will help you find your control and then you should be able to move the Top and Left fields to move the Image.  You could probably cast it as an image or button.

Comment: @xstreaminsanity He doesn't need to do anything complicated to find the control - it has a name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Layer_22_copy.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newTopValue);
Layer_22_copy.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newLeftValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Margin Property like

```
Layer_22_copy.Margin = new Thickness(10, 30, 0, 0);
```

Comment: what's deference between margin and canvas.left and right property?

Comment: No big difference. If, you hosted the image inside a canvas you could use the Canvas.Left or Top or Right or Bottom.

But, you can set margin even if you hosted it in Grid or in any custom panel. Also, It will reduce the number of lines. :)

Comment: There's a difference when it comes to layout and where things actually are, but that only matters if you're trying to figure out offsets between controls and things like that.